# Tools for creating interactive chart

Tags: silverlight, flash, visualization

I am creating a project which involves the visualisation of signals and timeline, so I am looking for a charting program which allows me to zoom in and zoom out and with additional functionality e.g. drag and drop or highlight the area.

I have no preference whether it should be WinForms or Web apps, and I am fine to program in either Flash or Silverlight. So I would like to see if you guys can recommend some tools for use. Thank you in advance

Regards,
Andy.

Comment: What's a "signal"?  Can you give a little more detail on what the chart might look like?

Answer (score 1):

Some Flash options:

- [Google Charts - Annotated Timeline](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html) - Flash, requires use of foreign API over the wire
- [AnyChart](http://www.anychart.com/products/anygantt/docs/users-guide/time_line_plot_elements.html) - Flash, commercial
- [Prefuse Timeline](http://www.prodevtips.com/demos/prefuse-flare/WordTrends_Zooming.swf) - Flash, open source.  This example pans and zooms, but the mousewheel zoom is far too coarse, try ctrl+mouse-drag

You didn't mention JS, but it might be worth looking at Flot, gRaphael, HighCharts or Protovis - there's a great breakdown of javascript timeline optionts on this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890434/javascript-library-for-drawing-graphs-over-timelines-zoomable-and-selectable/1951508#1951508).

Answer (score 0):

If you think the application would work as well as a web application, I don't see any reason to do it in forms.  As far as charting goes, there is charting built into Flash Builder professional if you want to go that route.  For Silverlight, there is the ToolKit and a number of 3rd party control vendors such as Telerik.  Both platforms will do what you need to do.

If you already know .NET then the decision should be a no-brainer, use Silverlight.